# nftables port forward causes network requests to fail

Tags: port-forwarding, nftables

I am trying to forward some ports from a public IP `172.10.22.22` to a remote VPN IP `10.22.22.22`. The local VPN IP is `10.22.22.1`

The ethernet interface is eth0
The wireguard vpn interface is wg0

These nftable rules work well except for the fact that other network requests are now dropped

```
table ip nat {
        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                masquerade
        }

        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 172.10.22.22 tcp dport { 3396 } dnat to 10.22.22.22;
                ip daddr 172.10.22.22 udp dport 10000-10100 dnat to 10.22.22.22;
        }
}
```

so `ping www.google.com` doesn't work.
How should I modify these rules? Please advise.

**Edit**

instead of `chain postrouting ...masquerade`, if I use `ofiname "wg0" masquerade`, the problem goes away. Do I need to make the masquerade expression any more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The problem is solved by making the masquerade expression in post-routing chain more specific.

```
table ip nat {
        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                # masquerade (as in question)
                ofiname "wg0" masquerade
        }

        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 172.10.22.22 tcp dport { 3396 } dnat to 10.22.22.22;
                ip daddr 172.10.22.22 udp dport 10000-10100 dnat to 10.22.22.22;
        }
}
```